# Query expression with activity party took 20 seconds to execute

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm trying to get appointments which have an account from special list in required attendees. Here's how I build a query.

```
var query = new QueryExpression("appointment")
{
    ColumnSet = columnSet,
    Criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And)
    {
        Conditions =
            {
                new ConditionExpression("scheduledstart", ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, DateTime.Now),
                new ConditionExpression("scheduledstart", ConditionOperator.LessEqual, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)),
                new ConditionExpression("statuscode", ConditionOperator.In, new []{1, 5})
            }
    }
};

var le = new LinkEntity
{
    LinkFromEntityName = "activitypointer",
    LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
    LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
    LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
    LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
    {
        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or,
        Conditions =
            {
                new ConditionExpression("partyid", ConditionOperator.Equal, accountGuid)
            }
    }
};
```

And adding conditions to link expression

```
 _accountRepository.GetAccounts()
                .Select(a => new ConditionExpression("partyid", ConditionOperator.Equal, a.Id))
                .ForEach(c => le.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(c));
```

This request is taking near 20 seconds to execute.
Any ideas why?

Comment: You should probably take a profiler and look how your queries is executed in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that executing queries with expressions using date fields (as you have done - using scheduledstart) can be slow.

The reason is that CRM needs to convert the field to local time, which seems slow.

Can you try:

1. Does removing the date expressions significantly increase the speed?
2. Can you use scheduledstart**utc** (which doesn't try to localise the date)?

Mike

Comment: thank for reply.first didin't help. and appointment does not have field scheduledstartutc